# Change Django model relations without saving them

Tags: django, django-models

I want to change properties from related models of a certain model, but I don't want to save them, I just want to change them temporarily.

Take for example these models:

```
class Duck(models.Model):
    name = models.StringField()

class Duckling(models.Model):
    name = models.StringField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Duck, related_name='children')
```

Now assume there is some data in the database, then when you try this:

```
for duckling in some_duck.children.all():
    duckling.name = 'test-to-change-name'

for duckling in some_duck.children.all():
    print(duckling.name)
```

In the second for loop it will print the original names and not the names we set in the first for loop. If you would `save()` them in the first for loop, it would work, but I want to change their names temporarily, just for this process.

Does anyone have an idea if this might be possible somehow? I was thinking of maybe overwriting `some_duck.children`, but then I would need to create a `RelatedManager` object myself, which is kind of weird and probably hacky. I hope there are better ways.

Edit: I want it to be updated on the `some_duck` object, so that when you access `some_duck.children` that you get the updated data over there.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the children queryset to a list?

```
children = list(some_duck.children.all())

for duckling in children:
    duckling.name = 'test-to-change-name'

for duckling in children:
    print(duckling.name)
```

Comment: Yes that would of course work, but when you would access it from the `some_duck` object you'll still get the same result. Sorry, this is a requirement, I'll update the question.